# How to add boost libraries to a Visual Studio Linux project?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, boost

I have created a little chat server which I have tested and compiled on Windows without any problems. The next step would be to put this server on my Raspberry Pi. But at that point I'm getting many errors.

I created a Visual Studio Remote Linux Project which I have conntected to my Raspberry Pi. I think that the compiler cannot find the libraries.

Some errors which I get(total errors are about 700):

> -Error (active)   E0304   no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::buffer"   matches the argument list
>   -Error (active)   E0020   identifier "sa_family_t" is undefined   VoiceChatServer 
>   -Error (active)   E0059   function call is not allowed in a constant expression
>   -Error (active)   E2778   builtin function is not available because vector types are not supported
>   -Error (active)   E0035   #error directive: Only Windows, POSIX and std::thread are supported!

My Project Properties look like that:
VC++ Directories > Include Directories: C:\Program Files\Cpp_Libs\boost_1_66_0,
/home/pi/boostPrefix/include/,
C:\includeLinux\include,
/usr/include/

C/C++ > Additional Include Directories: C:\Program Files\Cpp_Libs\boost_1_66_0,
/home/pi/boostPrefix/include/,
C:\includeLinux\include,
/usr/include/

Linker > Additional Library Directories: /home/pi/boostPrefix/lib/,
C:\Program Files\Cpp_Libs\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib

Does anybody know how to include the libraries correctly?

Comment: @VTT I did everything according to this tutorial: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html (Step 5.1). So it should be complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boost::asio is a header-only library, i.e. you simply specify the path to boost::asio source in the include directory path but it does depend on some other libraries with compiled binaries (object files). You must list these additonal libraries in the Visual Studio project under `Linker - Input - Library Dependencies`. E.g. in the case of Boost.System specify `boost_system` and the linker will add the `lib` prefix and `.a` or `.so` extension.

This is something extra you must do on Linux, on Windows Boost automatically adds the library references thru a Visual Studio directive.

I'm curious about how you've installed Boost; it looks to me like your include path on the Linux remote is `/home/pi/boostPrefix/include`. If you have followed the standard Boost install procedure (`boostrap.sh` and `b2`) the Boost headers will be in `/.../boost_1_66_0/boost/asio`, the include path you specify in the Visual Studio project `C/C++ > Additional Include Directories` will be `/.../boost_1_66_0` and in your C++ code you will write `#include <boost/asio>`

Incidentally, you do not need to specify `/usr/include` in the library path, GCC looks there by default.

Comment: You saved me. I was banging my head since morning. Pardon my ignorance, but I still did not understand what is the use of bootstrap.sh and prefix? why do we need to install b2? I' believe the single *apt-get* command is enough.

Comment: `bootstrap.sh` queries your system configuration to create a `b2` command file that is tailored to you and the libraries you want to install. If you download Boost directly from `www.boost.org` then you should follow this route. If you install Boost from your distro, with `apt-get` etc., then the library has already been built to a standard configuration of your distro. Be aware that distro provided libraries are often several versions behind.