# Cross-Platform Compiling on Visual Studio 2017 for RaspberryPi using Boost Libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to create a console application using C++ for RaspberryPi. I am using Visual Studio Community 2017, version 15.7.4. I created [a new project for Cross-Platform compiling for Linux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/). I tried a simple Hello World app and it is working. My problem is that I am not able to use Boost Libraries when I am cross-compiling.

For testing it, I chose [this tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) from Boost itself. I build Boost libraries according to this ["Getting Started on Windows" tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). So far, everything is normal and working as long as I compile it for Windows. Therefore, I can say there is no problem with library installation.

Using ["Getting Started on Unix Variants" tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), I built Boost libraries on my RaspberryPi as well. Using CMake on RaspberryPi, I was able to compile some examples from the tutorial and it is working.

In general, I am able to compile using Boost libraries on both platforms but when I try to compile on Windows for Linux using Boost libraries, VS2017 can't somehow find my libraries.

[image: An example of errors I get when I cross-compile]

[image: How I have been trying to include the libraries]

Comment: If you're not yet familiar with C++, cross-compiling doesn't exactly make things easier. And I know you're not familiar because you're not seeing the distinction between header files and libraries. The errors are about compile-time problems, which means that the library build process is irrelevant.

Comment: You're right, I am not exactly familiar but I know the difference. The reason why I thought it was a library problem is that without using/not having to include the Boost libraries, I can cross-platform. I am getting these errors only when I am using and probably failing to include these libraries. I will be updating the original post with another screenshot of my project configuration.

Comment: Have you read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898806/how-to-add-boost-libraries-to-a-visual-studio-linux-project/49908958#49908958